# Viewing traceback info when developing for Tizen Gear watch?

Tags: debugging, watch, tizen, traceback

I was recently given a Samsung Gear S2 and asked to develop with it. I have some experience working with Andorid and find the two to be similar, however I can not find any tracebacks from when my Tizen apps crash. I have tried opening command prompt and running "sdb.exe dlog" which shows some messages while things are happening, but nothing that appears to be a traceback to my original code. Am I debugging properly or just not looking in the right place? Do Tizen Watch web apps/ native apps/widget apps even produce tracebacks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Use**

dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Your error message with return code %d", ret);

For different type of log you can use DLOG_ERROR, DLOG_DEBUG, DLOG_DEFAULT, DLOG_INFO etc.

**To view LOGS go to:**

Tizen IDE > Window > Show View > Log

In Log view you can turn on/off log types, you will see that there are [V], [D] (debug), [I] (info), [W] (warning), [E] (error) and [F] (fatal) icons.

You can turn those ON/OFF to show/hide those type of logs. Do not forget to check if these are ON or OFF, if not ON no log will be shown.

Also DO NOT FORGET TO RUN IN DEBUG MODE.

Hope that helps.